# Error when I create a security group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

When I try to create a security group I get this error:

```
VPC-by-Default customers cannot use cluster security groups 
(Service: AmazonRedshift; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 7afbb99f-1f1d-11e8-9bf0-1fe6c55b7cfc) 
(Service: AmazonRedshift; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue; Request ID: 7afbb99f-1f1d-11e8-9bf0-1fe6c55b7cfc)
```

What does this mean and how do I solve it?

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=524592

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=524617) to the forum message, [Restore Snapshot doesn't allow --vpc-security-group-ids](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=524592):

> You can grant access to IPs by adding rules to your VPC security group. First, you can call describe-clusters to determine the VPC security groups your cluster is using. If the cluster is not associated with any VPC security group, you can call modify-cluster and specify the VPC security group IDs you want to use. After you have associated a VPC security group with the Redshift cluster, you can modify the security group in the VPC console to allow access from certain IPs (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_SecurityGroups.html#SecurityGroupRules).
>
> Note that in order for the Redshift cluster to be accessible from outside of the VPC, the cluster needs to be set to be publicly-accessible.

Comment: Please edit your answer and provide a link to the forum post